# Raspberry Pi Pico not working

Tags: raspbian

Having received a **Raspberry Pi Pico 2021 H** and a **10-DOF IMU** (coupled to my Pico), I watched videos to understand because I don't know anything about it: Thonny installed, UF2 file downloaded.

I press **BOOTSEL** and insert the micro-USB cable at the same time, I release 2s later but nothing happens. In the console of Thonny, I have a message that the device was not detected automatically, etc.. A red LED is lit on "**PWR**" on the 10-DOF IMU, thus indicating to me that a current passes between my PC and my Raspberry Pi Pico.

What to do?

Comment: Did it work with the IMU not connected?

Comment: Unfortunately no...

Comment: please edit your first question instead of posting a second question

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason why this doesn't work is because you are using a power-only (charger) USB cable. These are the normal type of cable that comes with any device that can be charged through USB. You need a proper data cable, such as supplied through reputable RPi suppliers, which has all four wires in it (+5V, GND, Tx and RX).

The other possibility is that the USB ports are restricted on your computer. If it's a personal computer though, then that is unlikely.

The third - least likely - possibility is that there's a problem with Thonny's config.

So steps to take:

1. Plug in a USB "thumb drive" to your computer and check it appears as a drive in Windows, is mounted in Linux etc.
2. If that works, press and hold the boot/sel on the Pico, insert the USB cable and release the button. It should appear just like the thumb drive. If it doesn't, you'll need a proper data cable.
3. If it does appear as a drive, but Thonny doesn't display the "Install MicroPython firmware..." dialog, then you likely have a problem with Thonny's configuration